# why present perfect tense used in below sentence and why there is no subject for word found

Tags: verbs, tenses

Scientists and researchers from the University of Delhi and the Zoological Survey of India have discovered a genus of tree frog found in the Andaman islands and the northeast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Have discovered' is in the present perfect because the scientists and researchers have completed the action and the subject of 'found' is the species of tree frog.

This is not immediately obvious, perhaps,  because 'found' is in the passive voice. It means that individuals of the species (and therefore the species as a whole) have been and can still be found in the places mentioned: not that the species has found anything.

Another example of 'found' in the passive voice would be "The dementia patient, who had escaped from his care home, was found wandering the streets."

Comment: Please check for duplicates. People have been known to downvote bloat-answers.